# Problem with saving a property of an object after validation

Tags: django, forms, validation

In my CreateView class I created an instance of my Wholesale_Client model.

Inside form_valid() function I am fetching from my form some information which I will use in create_woocommerce_client_individually() function in order to post this record in my woocommerce website.

Every user in woocommerce website has a post id which I have it as attribute in my Wholesale_Client model.

My aim is after storing the wholesale client instance in my db and in woocommerce website(successfully), to fetch the current stored wholesale client record in order to update the post id of this user(from null to post id).

How can I update information after fetching the record?

Here is my code:

Function for creating a woocommerce client in the website

```
def create_woocommerce_client_individually(wcapi,name,surname,email):
        data = {

            "first_name": name,    
            "last_name": surname,
            "email": email,
            }
        wcapi.post("customers", data).json()
```

Function for giving the customer id from woocommerce website , using the api, to my record.

```
def give_cid_to_client_individually(wcapi,email):


    r=wcapi.get("customers?email="+str(email)).json()
    post_id=r[0]['id']

    fetched_client=Wholesale_Client.objects.get(email=email)
    fetched_client.cid=int(post_id)
    fetched_client.save()
```

**Here (is the problem) despite the fact that the record is fetched successfully the post_id is not saved to the cid attribute of my model.**

My CBV

```
class WholesaleClientCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Wholesale_Client
    form_class = WholesaleClientForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('wholesale_clients_list')
    template_name='wholesale_clients/wholesale_client_create_form.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
        print("Inside form valid...\n")

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = WholesaleClientForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                wcapi=get_wcapi()
                create_woocommerce_client_individually(wcapi,name,surname,email)
                form.save()
                give_cid_to_client_individually(wcapi,email)
            else:
                form = WholesaleClientForm() 


        return super(WholesaleClientCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to call the `self.object` to have reference on the current object of my model in order to update correctly the desired property(cid).

Here is the solution:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        print("Inside form valid...\n")

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = WholesaleClientForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():

                self.object = form.save(commit=False)
                name=self.object.name
                #print("name : {} ".format(name))
                surname=self.object.surname
                #print("surname : {} ".format(name))
                email=self.object.email
                #print("email : {} \n".format(email))
                wcapi=get_wcapi()
                create_woocommerce_client_individually(wcapi,name,surname,email)

                r=wcapi.get("customers?email="+str(email)).json()
                post_id=r[0]['id']

                self.object.cid=post_id
                self.object.save()

            else:
                form = WholesaleClientForm() 


        return super(WholesaleClientCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```